# Get openlayers map data live while user interacts with map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-7

I'm creating a webapp using openlayers (version 7.2) and I'm trying to figure out how to have a live output of the current center, zoom & rotation.  I have found the 'movestart' and 'moveend' events however these both fire only once either at the beginning or end of the user interaction.  I'm trying to find a way to continually update the information while the user is interacting.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have using 'moveend' can anyone help me have this update while the user is still dragging/repositioning the map?

Here is my current code as well as alink to a JSFiddle.
Thanks.

```
HTML

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="output">
    <h2>Map Information</h2>
    Center Position: <span id="center" class="info"></span><br>
    Current Zoom: <span id="zoom" class="info"></span><br>
    Current Rotation: <span id="rotation" class="info"></span>
</div>





CSS

#map{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#output{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    width: calc(100% - 340px);
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}

#output h2{
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.info{
    font-size: smaller;
}

JS

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-63.5859487, 44.648618]), //halifax
    zoom: 14
  })
});

map.on("moveend", function() {
  var view = map.getView();
  var center = ol.proj.transform(view.getCenter(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  var zoom = view.getZoom();
  var zoomInfo = 'Zoom level = ' + zoom;
    var rotation = view.getRotation();
  document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = center;
  document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;
    document.getElementById('rotation').innerHTML = rotation;


});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/chudnovskym/d9cjzb03/21/](https://jsfiddle.net/chudnovskym/d9cjzb03/21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use change events on the view

```
map.getView().on(['change:center', 'change:resolution', 'change:rotation'], function() {
  var view = map.getView();
  var center = ol.proj.transform(view.getCenter(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  var zoom = view.getZoom();
  var zoomInfo = 'Zoom level = ' + zoom;
  var rotation = view.getRotation();
  document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = center;
  document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = zoom;
  document.getElementById('rotation').innerHTML = rotation;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nvtf26h0/

Comment: Thanks @Mike! This is axactly what I needed. Do I have to use all three (center, resolution, rotation)? or is there one option that would capture ALL changes?  Also, what other changes might there be that would alter my map.  Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Those three properties define the view.  In some cases you might need the `change:size` and `change:view` events of the map, but that should not be needed when you have a fixed size map div and don't reset the view (e.g. as in https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/projection-and-scale.html)